# Blender 2.80: How to obtain a white background using the workbench render engine?

Tags: rendering, workbench-render-engine

I'm trying to obtain a white background for a render using the workbench render engine. I have set the "Viewport Display" inside *World* settings to white but the background renders light grey.

What is the correct procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the values to more than one, say ten or more (up to 50).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Would love to get an explanation to why this works :)

Comment: The magic number is 16.3 when using filmic as color transform.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use the workflow you described in the question by setting the `Viewport Display` to `World` and turning the world to white, or you go for `Viewport Display` -> `Viewport`:

[image: BG Color]

However, you need to be aware that the Viewport runs internally through Color Management, so the Filmic Transform is applied. To get pure white, `2 to the power of 6.5 multiplied with 0.18` will give pure white (`16.29174023` that is). Not recommended though.

Comment: By the way, it is impossible (at least in version 3.1.2) to set the RGB or HSV values more than 1.0 here.

Comment: @DRCB That's correct. All of this goes back to a change the Blender Developers made a while after this question was asked. Since that change, the Viewport does NOT got through the View Transform (in my answer sloppily called "Color Management") any longer. So when you set it to (1,1,1) and work on an sRGB Display, that background will be white as requested.